# Average number of ancestors

Tags: family-tree, statistics, pedigree

Every individual has two parents, four grand-parents and so on. This would yield an astronomical number of ancestors even after a small number of generations, e.g. 2<sup>35</sup> ∼ 34 billions. The solution to this paradox is called [pedigree collapse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pedigree_collapse) which takes into account that some of the ancestors in the binary [Ahnentafel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahnentafel) are identical, i.e. one and the same subject. This leads to a decrease of the number of ancestors of a given generation.

> Are there any empirical statistics about the average number of ancestors of
>   generation -1, -2, -3, etc. in a given population.

The average number of parents is exactly 2, the average number of grand-parents is slightly less than 4, and so on.

Which mathematical model might yield sensible numbers? Does anyone know a reference?

Comment: We've talked about pedigree collapse here http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/3105/104

Comment: Would you be able to edit your Question to indicate whether you are hoping for global figures, or for a particular country, or ... ?

Comment: I have a feeling that somewhere, some years ago, I saw an article attempting to analyse (though perhaps not quantify) the amount of pedigree collapse. It *may* have been an article in the (UK) Society of Genealogists' Journal. Does this ring any bells with anyone?

Comment: Google does not immediately provide an obvious model but I suspect it might help if I knew what words to search for... However, Andrew Millard's article on this link http://community.dur.ac.uk/a.r.millard/genealogy/EdwardIIIDescent.php - while it aims at the inverse problem as it were - seems to provide a few names, phrases and concepts to search for.

Comment: @AdrianB: nope re SoG, and the search facilities on their site are woeful.

Comment: I think some of the answers in the discussion by ColeValleyGirl start to address the question and like Verbeia answer mentions there are a lot of undefined criteria to the question. I guess my question is, what is the purpose of what you are trying to utilize the answer, is it for a guide or are you truly trying to look for a "Mathematical Model" that utilizes a series of predictor variables from a large set of predictor variables associated in genealogy. My guess DNA analysis would provide the simplest and most precise answer though more than a mathematical model.

Comment: @HansStricker Since my comment a month ago I found some good papers on this topic, I am working on a summation of those papers and journal articles but I do not believe a linear model *Y = B0 + B1(x1) + B2(X2)^Z1* will be part of the answer or are you looking for that level of answer to this question as I could reference some of those but from what I have read no one claims to have a perfect model and use and results will vary? Can you clarify expectation?